# Rearrange generic list after sequence update in c#

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, sorting

Let's say I have a generic List such as this:

```
var categories = new List<Category>() {
    new Category() { sequence = 3, categoryName = "Category F" },
    new Category() { sequence = 1, categoryName = "Category S" },
    new Category() { sequence = 2, categoryName = "Category Z" },
    new Category() { sequence = 4, categoryName = "Category X" },
    new Category() { sequence = 5, categoryName = "Category V" }
};
```

I'm trying to replace the given sequence number with another i.e. update item in the list with sequence# 2 with number 5 as below:

```
int currSeq = 2;
int newSeq = 5;
var item = categories.Find(a => a.sequence == currSeq);
item.sequence = newSeq;
```

If the newSeq were not become duplicate e.g. newSeq = 6, I could just do OrderBy:

```
categories = categories.OrderBy(c => c.sequence).ToList();
```

But the problem is when they become duplicates, I need the newSeq become in sequence# 5 and bump the other duplicated sequence# 5 + 1.

Please help with any guidance solving this. Thanks.

Update: certain cases when new sequence < old sequence, the output is not as desired.

Scenario A:

```
var categories = new List<Category>() {
    new Category() { sequence = 3, categoryName = "Category F" },
    new Category() { sequence = 1, categoryName = "Category S" },
    new Category() { sequence = 2, categoryName = "Category Z" },
    new Category() { sequence = 5, categoryName = "Category X" },
    new Category() { sequence = 6, categoryName = "Category V" }
};
int currSeq = 2;
int newSeq = 1;
var result = categories.UpdateSequence(currSeq,newSeq).OrderBy(x=>x.sequence);
```

Output Scenario A:

```
1: Category S
3: Category Z
4: Category F
5: Category X
6: Category V
```

Desired Output Scenario A:

```
1: Category Z
2: Category S
3: Category F
5: Category X
6: Category V
```

Scenario B:

```
int currSeq = 3;
int newSeq = 1;
var result = categories.UpdateSequence(currSeq,newSeq).OrderBy(x=>x.sequence);
```

Output Scenario B:

```
1: Category Z
2: Category S
4: Category F
5: Category X
6: Category V
```

Desired Output Scenario B:

```
1: Category F
2: Category S
3: Category Z
5: Category X
6: Category V
```

Comment: Well, use Linq again. First determine whether your _categories_ list has a Category object that has the same _sequence_ number as _newSeq_. If no such Category object exists, you don't need to increment. Otherwise, _Select_ from your categories list the _Category_ objects whose _sequence_ numbers are equal or greater than _newSeq_, and increment _sequence_ of those _Category_ objects. Done...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update based on comment and Edited OP.**

Assuming your Category class is defined as following.

```
public class Category
{
    public int sequence{get;set;}
    public string categoryName{get;set;}
}
```

You can write the Update Sequence method as follows to get the desired result when newValue < oldValue.

```
 public static List<Category> UpdateSequence(this List<Category> categories, int oldValue,int newValue)
 {
        var invalidState = -1;
        if(oldValue>newValue)
        {
            categories.Single(x=>x.sequence == oldValue).sequence = invalidState;
            if(categories.Any(x=>x.sequence == newValue))
            {
                categories = UpdateSequence(categories, newValue,newValue+1);
            }
            categories.Single(x=>x.sequence == invalidState).sequence = newValue;
        }
        else
        {
            if(categories.Any(x=>x.sequence == newValue))
            {
                categories = UpdateSequence(categories, newValue,newValue+1);
            }
            categories.Single(x=>x.sequence==oldValue).sequence = newValue;
        }
        return categories;
    }
```

**Input**

```
var categories = new List<Category>() {
    new Category() { sequence = 3, categoryName = "Category F" },
    new Category() { sequence = 1, categoryName = "Category S" },
    new Category() { sequence = 2, categoryName = "Category Z" },
    new Category() { sequence = 5, categoryName = "Category X" },
    new Category() { sequence = 6, categoryName = "Category V" }
```

**Scenario 1:**

```
int currSeq = 2;
int newSeq = 1;
var result = categories.UpdateSequence(currSeq,newSeq).OrderBy(x=>x.sequence);
```

**Output**

```
1 Category Z 
2 Category S 
3 Category F 
5 Category X 
6 Category V
```

**Scenario 2**

```
int currSeq = 3;
int newSeq = 1;
var result = categories.UpdateSequence(currSeq,newSeq).OrderBy(x=>x.sequence);
```

**Ouput**

```
1 Category F 
2 Category S 
3 Category Z 
5 Category X 
6 Category V
```

Comment: thanks so much, however when newValue < oldValue it should increments any sequence < oldValue

Comment: @joegreentea I have updated the answer for the case you mentioned. Could you verify if that is the desired output. If not, could you please mention the desired output in the scenario ?

Comment: yes, that would be the desired output when new sequence < old sequence - I tried but couldn't figure out how to get that kind of output

Comment: The output I had posted was based on the same code. Would you be able to update the OP with the exact scenario where you are having issues  and the desired output in such a scenrio

Comment: @joegreentea Have updated the answer based on new examples you had proved. Kindly verify

Answer (score 0):

Do what elgonzo said in his comment.  Plus start out with widely spaced sequence numbers, i.e. 1000, 2000, 3000 rather than 1,2,3.  I don't know your use case, but unless you are reordering a lot, this will minimize the number of "bumps" of sequence numbers you have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have sorted the list based on the `Sequence` already, you can use the `FindIndex` method of LINQ to find the index of element with `currSeq` and `newSeq` and then use `RemoveAt` along with `Insert` to place the updated element at correct position.

Something like this:

```
int currSeq = 2;
int newSeq = 5;
var oldIndex = categories.FindIndex(i => i.Sequence == currSeq);
var newIndex = categories.FindIndex(i => i.Sequence == newSeq);

if(oldIndex > -1)
{
    var oldItem = lst[oldIndex];
    oldItem.ID = newSeq;

    if(newIndex > -1)
    {
        newIndex = newIndex-1 < 0 ? 0 : newIndex - 1;    //in case the first element is the existing one
        categories.RemoveAt(oldIndex);
        categories.Insert(newIndex, oldItem);
    }
    else
    {
        categories = lst.OrderBy(i => i.ID).ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your issue. But when inserting all following lines are moved too. Is this okay for you?

```
    var categories = new List<Category>() {
        new Category() { sequence = 3, categoryName = "Category F" },
        new Category() { sequence = 1, categoryName = "Category S" },
        new Category() { sequence = 2, categoryName = "Category Z" },
        new Category() { sequence = 4, categoryName = "Category X" },
        new Category() { sequence = 5, categoryName = "Category V" }
    };

    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        list.Add("");
    }

    foreach (var item in categories)
    {
        list[item.sequence] = item.categoryName;
    }

    var removeFrom = 2;
    var removeTo = 5;

    list.Insert(removeTo, list[removeFrom]);
    list.RemoveAt(removeFrom);
```